# Java bounded generic constraints on fields

Tags: java, generics

There have been a couple of times when I've felt the need to do something like the following:

```
private <T extends Type> Map<GenericClass1<T>,GenericClass2<T>> map;
```

...or something to that effect. Essentially, using an identical bound in the two arguments for map. (This isn't an actual example, just shows the idea.)

I know this (unfortunately) isn't possible and that it's only available on class definitions and method signatures. My question however is why isn't it available on fields? Is it purely a design choice or is there some technical reason behind it that I'm missing? I've had a think and can't see why this shouldn't be possible from a technical perspective, as far as I can see everything is there for the compiler to work it out correctly and none of the generic information is required at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<T> means ONE class, not A class.
When your object is instanced T is bound to this ONE class.

You are trying to put two objects with diffrent interfaces (used diffrently because they take/return diffrent types) in to the same container. This is a error because when you take them out of the container (the map) you dont know what it was you put in.

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Edit: That said you can have a container that holds members based on there class, to automatically  create a new map for EACH type of T. You would then need to know what T was in order to access it.
In general, if you dont want the type information anymore, throw it away. If you do then  putting it in the same container as something of another type will throw it away anyway for all practical reasons.

Comment: @"none of the generic information is required at runtime", if the compiler let you do stuff based on what was possible at runtime then your language is not typed any more. Typing IS the restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see what you're saying, but where I could see this being useful is if you know the generic parameter of the key, you can guarantee that you'll get an object back of the exact same generic bound.

Comment: If you know the type of a object, cast it. but if you ever do if( x instance of y) you are most likely doing it wrong. Save the type instead.

Comment: hmm if I understand you correctly... public function <T> T get(class<T> c). Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you want to instantiate your `map` variable. Theoretically you will have to write something like this:

```
map = new HashMap<GenericClass1<String>,GenericClass2<String>>();
```

Ok. But now what does not make sense to me *anymore* is what arguments the `put` or `get` methods will accept/return? `T`? Uh... what is `T`? `GenericClass1|2<String>`? Again makes no sense, does it? After all I see no `String` in the `map` declaration. So I guess there is no really correct instantiation and usage of this generic variable.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, how I have longed for something like:

```
private <T> Map<Class<T>, T> instanceCache;

public <T> T getInstanceOf(Class<T> clazz) {
    return instanceCache.get(clazz);
}
```

But as you mentioned, it's completely impossible in Java. The method declaration above is fine, but there's no way to declare the variable such that there's not a cast in the method. Simply add this to the growing list of things you hate about generics and move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` as following:

`private List<? extends List> l = new ArrayList<List>();`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm after - I know I can use basic wildcards in that fashion, but I want to capture the exact same bound (in the question, T) across multiple generic parameters. I could use "? extends Type" twice, but that won't guarantee the same bound, it could be two different classes that extend Type.